# Many buttons do similar tasks - is there a way to simplify actionPerformed?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, action

I currently have a set of buttons which when pressed, update an element of an array with their value and then close the frame which contains them.

Currently, their actions are set out like this:

```
...
svwnb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = svwnb.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    blypb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = blypb.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    pw91b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = pw91b.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    b97db.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = b97db.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    pbepbesolb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = pbepbesolb.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
...
```

Is there a way of simplifying this into a simple method? I've got a feeling I'll need to use the `getSource()` method but I have no experience in constructing an action method like this.

To be more succinct, I have an idea that the code will look something like the following pseudocode:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     input[5] = e.getSource().getText();
     dftframe.setVisible(false);
 }
```

I just don't know exactly how to generate this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the ActionListener in the following way:

```
ActionListener commonListener = new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();
        if (o instanceof JTextField) {
            JTextField textField = (JTextField)o;
            input[5] = textField.getText();
            textField.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
};
```

And use it by adding it to each component:

```
svnwnb.addActionListener(commonListener);
...
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yep. It's ugly. I wanted to say, that the questioner can define a (private) field of type ActionListener in his class. I'll edit it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `e` in your psudo code else everything should work fine.

```
input[5] = e.getSource().e.getText(); 
                         ^
```

This should be

```
input[5] = e.getSource().getText();
```

You might need an extra cast to e.getSource() something like (Not sure if it is required or not)

```
input[5] = ((JButton)e.getSource()).getText();
```

There is also a getActionCommand method in ActionEvent which you can use but it will only work if you have proper actionCommand set in your buttons.

Comment: What structure will I use for this program if I use your proposed way?

each of my buttons has an .addActionListener appended to them with an actionPerformed method inside the argument.

How will I restructure my program to accomodate this? Thank you

Comment: No you will not require multiple action listener. Create only one ActionListener instance and add it to all buttons with similar actions. Then in actionPerformed use your pseudo code.

Comment: _Not sure if it is required or not_ why aren't you sure? The type of getSource is documented :-)

Answer (score -1):

Looking back at the source object is really dirty. Apart from that, the source is often surprising or undocumented. Just use a different instance of the listener for each button:

```
    addTextAction(svwnb);
    addTextAction(blypb);
    addTextAction(pw91b);
    addTextAction(b97db);
    addTextAction(pbepbesolb);
    ...

private void addTextAction(final AbstractButton button) {
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            input[5] = button.getText();
            dftframe.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
}
```

(Linking the button with the text seems a bit nasty. It should be obvious how to split that here (much less so if you try to hack it by getting the event source).)

Comment: Why do you think this is better than single instance of the listener? The purpose of the listener in the question is the same for each field. Only the source of the event varies.

Comment: Downvote. Your answer contains nothing but grunting. I also think, that everyone here should explain the reason for the downvote.